# Ember.js rendering template in other template not fetching model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having an issue where when I attempt to use the model from a different route it fails to work.

Here is working example with chart drawing from the model fetched from the index route: http://jsbin.com/kulefogoqera/1/edit

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?');
    }
});
```

I've modified it and did separate template called charts and now I want to render it into index route but can't get the model from charts route:
http://jsbin.com/yotinemubinu/1/edit

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
      console.log(this.modelFor('charts'));
        this.render('index');
        this.render('charts', {
            into: 'index',
            outlet: 'charts',
            controller: this.controllerFor('charts'),
            model: this.modelFor('charts')
        });
    }
});

App.ChartsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?');
    }
});
```

Is this a misconception from my side? Can a template only be rendered from the model hook from that route?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to __target specific programming problems__ - What's the _expected behaviour_, _specific error or unexpected behaviour you're getting_ (A clear problem statement), and a ___reproducible example___? Please take a __[tour]__. Also see a [__Minimal__, __Complete__, and __Verifiable__ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [__Short__, __Self Contained__, Correct (__Compilable__) example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I did that... I've wrote that i can't get data from charts model = this is the problem.

Comment: Code is on jsbin. working so it's easier to find the problem... You want me to paste 500 line of code here ?

Comment: Last time i've pasted partial code, i had 34 comments with 25 different WRONG proposals... in couple of hours.. now someone can open my link from jsbin and just check if his solution work.. and then paste PROPER answer. Really go and do something productive with your time instead of down voting something you didn't even analyzed. Thank you.

Comment: Now you removed your comments about down voting my question, why is that ?

Comment: This is a community of professionals helping other professionals.  If you are asking for help, you should do it in a professional manner.  Complaining about the way that answers are expected to be formatted is anything but professional.  Also, please remember, we all have our own jobs to do, and anything that takes more than a few minutes to look over will be ignored by many people; this includes having to look at another website for code.

Comment: Intention of giving link to JSBIN with working code and it's result was to make easier to answer my question, as i told before last time i didn't do that i had 25 wrong answers. Now everyone participating can check their anwser in couple of seconds without copying code or executing it anywhere locally. I am trying to make something faster and easier and i get comments that i am making it harder... And about your comment that people don't have time to watch other websites... JSBIN is commonly used on stackoverflow. That i've registered couple of days before != i am new here.

Comment: perhaps you should review the requirements for creating a question; it clearly states " Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: It's in the question, you just need to click on it. I don't see in there "code need to be in the question, not linked, not in any remote location". I've delivered code necessary to reproduce, clicking is not hard, you should try it.

Comment: this argument is completely distracting from the goal of getting your question an answer; I didn't even issue any downvotes, yet as I look at the jsbin pages side by side I'm not yet seeing the modification that broke the render, and I think that's the problem people are having.

Comment: Are you familiar with ember.js ? Maybe it's the problem. Because i see it without any problems. And i've wrote in description exactly what've changed. Anyone that is familiar with ember.js will know what needs to be done to achieve what i've stated changed. Anyone that doesn't see or know what changed can't answer that question anyway. I even got 2 of those like you said page side by side, first you can see on the left that there is new template called index and the one before is not called index but charts now.. On modified jsbin IndexRoute and IndexController changed to Charts etc..

Comment: since apparently I'm too stupid to know how this works, I'm not going to waste any more time looking for a way to help.  good luck finding an answer, though.

Comment: I didn't say that.. But the truth is that only second jsbin is enough to figure it out.. you do not need to compare it... If you know ember.. I did it only to show that it works when we have only index route.. But rendering seperate template inside index dosen't work.. I don't know what more i can add? In my last comment i've explained what changed.. maybe ask what can't you see then i will answer.. Really you first commented 40 minutes ago... If it took you so much time to know how it works (in second bin is like 100 basic lines of code.. ?) then maybe indeed don't waste your time..

Comment: If the shoe fits... Just kidding, hah, klonodo, I completely agree with the previous statements.  Just tossing up two jsbins and saying they don't work isn't appropriate or courteous.  You're asking for free help and then failing to show the differences between the two.  I had to toss them into a diff tool. I'll edit and show you what it should look like.

Comment: Hm maybe you are right Kingpin, maybe it's easy to see diffrenece for me beacuse i know exactly already what changed and i see it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
setupController: function() {
this.controllerFor('charts').set('promise', Ember.$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?'))
  }


});
```

And this change solves the problem :

```
App.ChartsController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin,{ ...
```

Working modified jsbin http://jsbin.com/yotinemubinu/5/edit

Answer (score 1):

`modelFor` won't fetch a model for a route that isn't hit.  It's just going to output undefined.  You can test this with `console.log`.  http://jsbin.com/yotinemubinu/4/edit

```
this.render('charts', {
  into: 'index',
  outlet: 'charts',
  controller: this.controllerFor('charts'),
  model: this.modelFor('charts')
});
```

Additionally you should be extending `ObjectController` instead of `Controller`.

You should read this section: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/

Comment: Thx! As i thought that it will not initialize because of not going into route.. i was thinking about merging models maybe in index into hash with RSVP promise or maybe use 2 diffrenet controllers to fetch both template models? What is the right path to go to achieve what i want?

Comment: I would start moving away from the index route, and start veering toward nested resources, here's a small example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1036/edit

Comment: I'd really recommend running through that one section of the guides to try an familiarize yourself with the router.

Comment: I want to render 2 different templates inside index but they are separate templates like charts that are not nested inside index. Basically i want then load them inside index separately ( that both of them can have isloading events that are seperate from each other,if one get data thru ajax first then it will be rendered first but another will still have spinner if it's fetching data). I don't know if nesting can help me here

Comment: In other words.. In index route i want to have 2 different templates rendered, both are independent = both can have their own custom loading event. I've tried to do that now with charts but data is not even fetching because of that what you said that route is not hitted = no ajax call in model. Both of the templates will load data via ajax call, both will fetch different data. How to achieve that ? I see now in this post http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/dashboard-type-views/5187/13  that someone had similiar to my problem. Is this the best road for that problem ?

Comment: You'll want to make use of properties in the controller, and render in the template, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1048/edit

Comment: Thx, but i figured it out myself already around 3 hours ago and posted answer, anyway thx for participating !